# Caliburn Micro: plugin-related questions for MEF-based scenario

Tags: mef, caliburn.micro

I have a scenario with a WPF application hosting some views (user controls) with their viewmodels, found as MEF exported parts in its plugin folder. The application loads its data together with a configuration file, which also tells which parts should be imported among the available ones.

**First question** is related to the MEF bootstrapper: how can I customize it in order to let it know about the plugins folder? I know of its *SelectAssemblies* override, but it requires assemblies, while my typical approach would be a MEF directory catalog. I would not want to use methods like *Assembly.LoadFrom* for each DLL found in the directory: MEF is there for this purpose (lifetime managing and the like). So how can I do something similar to a MEF *AggregateCatalog* built of *DirectoryCatalog*'s in the bootstrapper?

**Second question**: once I have the list of VM's I need, I want to instantiate them. Some of them require the injection of CM services like *IEventAggregator* or *IWindowManager*, so that they have a corresponding importing constructor and I thus require CM to instantiate them for me: but I need to do this programmatically, so I can't just use an Import attribute on a property or an importing constructor.

The same is true for views: once I have got my VM's, I need CM to create them and set the corresponding VM as their data context; but I cannot use a window manager because I just want to get them, and then programmatically add them (they are user controls) to a tab control, which is composed differently according to the data configuration.

I'm using MEF because the application is plugin-centric, and so I can stick with its limitations when used as a IoC. But I'd like to leverage CM for instantiating my views and viewmodels (all contained in several plugin DLL's) and bind them correctly. Could anyone give some hints or point to samples or documentation about this?

**Second update**, as promised :):

I essentially follow these steps:

1. instantiate (using MEF) the required VM's according to some application logic. All the VM's are MEF exports, hosted in several plugins in a plugins folder.
2. for each VM, call:

```
static private object LocateViewFor(object viewmodel)
{
  UIElement view = ViewLocator.LocateForModel(viewmodel, null, null);
    ViewModelBinder.Bind(viewmodel, view, null);
  return view;
}
```

This should istantiate my views via CM, which will also satisfy their imports and bind each view to its VM. The "standard" MefBootstrapper, modified for WPF, is used (see e.g. [here](http://buksbaum.us/2010/08/04/caliburn-micro-the-meftacluar)). Anyway, this does not work and returns null.

I must tell the bootstrapper where it can find my MEF exports. They are in the plugins folder, and if I weren't using CM I'd use a MEF DirectoryCatalog to inspect its content. The typical extension point for bootstrappers in CM is a SelectAssemblies override, which requires me to return a list of Assembly objects. Loading all the assemblies from a folder isn't an option. Following a suggestion in the above quoted page, I could do something like adding a method like this in my bootstrapper:

```
private IEnumerable GetDirectoryCatalogs()
{
 return new ComposablePartCatalog[]
 {
 new DirectoryCatalog(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory)
 // TODO other plugins folders...
  };
}
```

And modify its configuration code like:

```
_container = new CompositionContainer(
  new AggregateCatalog(AssemblySource.Instance.Select(x => new AssemblyCatalog(x)).OfType()
  .Union(GetDirectoryCatalogs())));
```

This effectively seems to load the required assemblies as for MEF, but it is not enough to "register" them into CM AssemblySource.Instance: infact, I can retrieve the VM's via MEF, but when I ask CM to get the corresponding view (either with the above method, or with a call to IWindowManager.ShowDialog(myviewmodel, null)) I get null from the method, or (for the second sample) the "placeholder" textbox saying that a view for my VM could not be located.

This seems related to the fact that the view, like the viewmodel, is hosted into a different assembly, my MEF plugin. I ensured that both the view and the viewmodel *share the same namespace*, and *follow the naming convention* of type SomeNamespace.SampleViewModel - SomeNamespace.SampleView; also, *both the view and the viewmodel are exported by decorating them with [Export]*, and derive from common interfaces. Nonetheless, I cannot get CM to work as expected when dealing with external assemblies. MEF work fine, with all its imports and exports, but as soon as CM enters the equation it cannot do its "magic" and locate a view from the VM.

Any hint?

Comment: Adding some considerations: I was thinking to something like UIElement view = ViewLocator.LocateForModel(viewmodel, null, null) to get a view from a VM, and ViewModelBinder.Bind(viewmodel, view, null) to bind them. Might this be OK? My questions anyway remain...

Answer (score 1):

I've never done anything with Caliburn Micro before, but does it use the `CompositionInitializer` component to satisfy imports? If so, you can use the `CompositionHost` to manually initialise the container used to satisfy imports, e.g.:

```
var catalog = new AggregateCatalog(
    new DirectoryCatalog("bin"),
    new DirectoryCatalog("Plugins"));

CompositionHost.Initialise(catalog);
```

Any calls to `CompositionInitialiser.SatisfyImports(...)` will use a container constructed from the catalogs you created.

If you are looking to be able to create instances of exports programmatically, you will need reference to the actual `CompositionContainer` itself. But to do this, we need another alternative way of initialising composition. You could create a container and hold a reference to it, e.g.:

```
var catalog = new AggregateCatalog(
    new DirectoryCatalog("bin"),
    new DirectoryCatalog("Plugins"));
var container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);
CompositionHost.Initialise(container);

Container = container;
```

...where `Container` is a static reference to your `CompositionContainer` instance. We've changed the call to `CompositionHost` to specificy the exact container that `CompositionInitializer` will use, so that all still works correctly, but we then have a container that we can use to create specific instances, e.g.:

```
var viewModel = Container.GetExport<ISomeViewModel>();
```

Does that help?

Comment: Thank you, this might be a good hint, but sadly the application I'm working on at the moment is a WPF application, and CompositionHost is not available. The typical MEF bootstrapper sampled for CM uses a CompositionHost for SL and a code like this for WPF: _container = new CompositionContainer(
new AggregateCatalog(AssemblySource.Instance.Select
(x => new AssemblyCatalog(x)).OfType<ComposablePartCatalog>()));

Comment: Can you update your code to present how you are constructing your container and how it wires into CM?

Comment: The final part of my edited post probably does the trick. Anyway, I'm still facing some issues with CM and MEF, some on the MEF part, so this is an argument for another post...:) When I get a clearer insight I'll try to update this post too.

Comment: For anyone who might be interested, I updated my question in the first post. It seems the problem lies in the fact that CM cannot locate the view when it's hosted into another assembly, even if the viewmodel lies in the same assembly, they follow the naming conventions and they are both [Export]ed with MEF.

Comment: If you search the discussion forums I've seen threads talking about this and how to fix it.